# Auto Reload page when browser/tab is idle

Tags: javascript, browser, settimeout, reload

I need some help here. Hope you guys can help me. I was trying to put this code on my page to auto reload the page when mouse and keypress is inactive.

```
<body onmousemove = "canceltimer()"; onclick = "canceltimer()"; onkeypress = "canceltimer()"; onscroll = "canceltimer()";
      onload = "canceltimer"; onmousedown = "canceltimer()">
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var tim = 0;
    function reload () {
tim = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);   // 3 minutes
}
    function canceltimer() {
window.clearTimeout(tim);  // cancel the timer on each mousemove/click
reload();  // and restart it
}
</script>
```

So far, It's working but only in mouse and keypress. somehow I would like to reload my page automatically if my browser or tab is idle. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.